# My hand rig breaks the hand fingers when making a fist

Tags: rigging, rigify

This is my first time rigging in Blender 2.9 and im trying to rig a hand and the fingers, but once i have everything rigged, and rotate the hand into a fist position, all of the fingers break, i have attached the .blend file, can i get some help?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bones are not correctly rotated, select your bones in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> *(Recalculate Roll) > Global X Axis* (for example):

[image]